# Localize Angular ui calendar

Tags: angularjs, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm building and agularjs application where I integrate angular ui calendar aka fullcalendar. I'm trying to tage advantage of its localization, but keeps getting an error. I tried including both lang-all.js and also a specific locale for my language danish "da".
As described in the [documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/lang/) I placed the language script after the calendar itself .

Both jquery and momentjs is included before this.
Is there any special language file etc. I need to get this working?

Best regards
Rasmus

Comment: What error are you getting?
Are you using the angular "UI Calendar"? If yes, you might want to check out the following link: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/ You might have to set some settings via  $scope.uiConfig

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the language you want to use. You can also import all languages but then you need to specify what language you are using with the option `lang`

See here: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/lang/

```
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/lang/sv.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({...});

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Hmmm this is also what I did, think I need to look further into what bower fetched, i'll be back :)